# How do I perform an addition of a templated struct?

Tags: c++

Currently I'm learning about structs and templated. I have a templated struct:

```
template<int value>
struct ConstInt
{
    static int  eval()
    {
        return value; 
    };
};
```

I want to achieve the following:

> Create an Add struct template that take two structs as template
> parameters.

An example of the usage is given below:

```
typedef Add<f, g> h; // represents the function h(x) = f(x) + g(x)
```

**What I did**

I first wrote a new templated struct:

```
template<ConstInt f, ConstInt g>
Struct Add
{
    return f + h; 
}
```

Operator overloading needs to be applied in my opinion:

```
ConstInt operator+(const ConstInt &other) const
{
        ConstInt temp1;
        temp1.value = value - other.value;
        return temp1;   
}
```

Here is where is goes wrong. I get the following error:

> error: template placeholder type 'const ConstInt<...auto...>' must be
> followed by a simple declarator-id

**Help**

In the first place I am not sure if my 'method' is the right way to achieve the task. This error doesn't make it clear to me why it fails. Could I please get feedback on this?

Nadine :)

Comment: Try: `template<class T> ConstInt<T> operator+(const ConstInt<T>& other)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `Struct`? Is `Add` a class template or function template? If it's a class template it can't return anything. Is `h` an object or type?

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that is not the solution. I get the following error: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<int value> struct ConstInt'
   15 | template<class T> ConstInt<T> operator+(const ConstInt<T>& other)

Comment: What showing what you "did", please show real code instead of code that's clearly invalid. No self-respecting C++ compiler will compile "Struct Add".

Comment: @thomasSablik , apologies for not providing all the information. Add is a struct template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this,

```cpp
template<int value>
struct ConstInt
{
    
    // Use constexpr as this method can be evaluated at compile time.
    static constexpr int eval()
    {
        return value;
    } // You dont need a semicolon here.
};

template<class a, class b>
struct Add 
{
    constexpr int operator()()
    {
        // You dont need to define a new addition operator because,
        // 1) Your always returning an integer value.
        // 2) C++ has a default addition operator for integers.
        return a::eval() + b::eval();
    }
};

int main()
{
    // I know this because I saw your last question ;)
    typedef ConstInt<5> a;
    typedef ConstInt<10> b;

    int v = Add<a, b>()();
}
```

Note that the `Add` struct wont work for every object. It'll only work for objects which have a static `eval()` method which returns an `int` value.

Comment: Choose between `eval` from OP, or traditional `operator()`, mixing both disallows `Add<ConstInt<20>, Add<ConstInt<20>, ConstInt<2>>>`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the value is actually stored in a template parameter, your `operator+` will need to be able to act on that. One way to accomplish this is to make `operator+` a function template:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int value>
struct ConstInt
{
    static int eval()
    {
        return value;
    }

    template<int rhs_value>
    ConstInt<value + rhs_value> operator+ (const ConstInt<rhs_value>&) const
    {
        return ConstInt<value + rhs_value>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    ConstInt<3> three;
    ConstInt<5> five;
    auto eight = three + five;
    std::cout << eight.eval();
}

// Output: 8
```

Note the return type of `operator+` depends on the template value of the right-hand side argument.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit strange of seeing a type for a const int when you just can use constexpr. However, it makes sense as a teaching exercise.

Their are multiple ways of solving your problem. I think the most generic way is via a freestanding `operator+`.

```
template<int value>
struct ConstInt
{
};

template <int a, int b>
constexpr auto operator+(ConstInt<a>, ConstInt<b>) -> ConstInt<a+b>
{
    return {};
}
```

As you can see in this code, ConstInt doesn't even need any member to do the calculation.

You could later add overloads for ConstDouble and ConstInt where the result becomes a ConstDouble.

Just for completeness:

```
auto f()
{
    constexpr int a = 40;
    constexpr int b = 2;
    constexpr int answer = a+b;
    return answer;
}
```

This code will be better for your compile time. It can't have undefined behavior. It will be calculated at compile time, even at -O0. And it's much more readable than the alternative.

Comment: In addition to learning technique, `ConstInt` might be the first brick of some kinds of AST (or expression template).